# Odds Ratio for log linear models

Tags: odds-ratio

[image]

I need to determine the odds ratio for membership in the Nazi Party for a rural Protestant teacher versus a rural teacher with no religious affiliation in Germany, I am familiar with determining odds ratio from a contingency table, however given that I can't access the data to do this and need to do it from the coefficient estimates I am lost as to how to do this, if anyone could point me in the right direction that would extremely helpful.

Comment: The question of which this is a duplicate has been removed..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my lay perspective, categorical analysis always automatically determines the baseline(reference group). Here (loglinear model) we compare the coefficient between two groups, membership-Protestant-rural and rural. So it is intuitive to see the value of rural is 0 (baseline), and so we find the offset, which is 
$$religionProtestent:membershipYes = 1.46613$$
Therefore, the log odd should be 1.46613 and the odd should be $exp(1.46613)=4.332436$

You may double check. Hope it helps.